# Moment JS update timezone abbreviation

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

Currently the timezone for the east coast is appearing as "EST", which is technically correct, but we need to update it to display as "ET".  Any advice in how to do this with moment js?

I tried replacing strings like this in moment-timezone.js, but it didn't appear to change it:

```
"America/Detroit|EST EDT|50 40|01010101010101010101010|1BQT0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0",
```

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, moment doesn't have generic forms of the abbreviations.  It only has abbreviations from the underlying [TZ database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Generic abbreviations for *some* time zones can be found in [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org), but there's currently no easy way to use these with Moment.

If you know the value is ET, you could always just format without the time zone abbreviation, then append it to the string afterwards.

```
var s = moment.tz("America/Detroit").format("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a") + " ET";
```